# What was the first automated theorem prover?

Tags: mathematics, computer-science

From a lot of googling, it seems like the answer might be "Mizar", but I am not completely sure.

**What was (or is?) the first automated theorem prover (i.e. not necessarily active right now)?**

Comment: It isn't Mizar (1973). [Wikipedia's history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving#First_implementations) lists implementations already from 1950-s, like Davis's program (1953) and Logic Theory Machine (1956).

Comment: Also relevant [Hao Wang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hao_Wang_(academic)) result of 1959: "In 1959, Wang wrote on an IBM 704 computer a program that in only 9 minutes mechanically proved several hundred mathematical logic theorems in Whitehead and Russell's *Principia Mathematica*." See [Toward mechanical mathematics (1960)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1147/rd.41.0002)

Comment: This question might be a bit broad,as any conjecture which can be proved is a theorem; many are pathologically trivial.  Could you try to limit it to certain "levels" of theorems, perhaps?

Comment: A good reference is [The Automation of Proof: A Historical and Sociological Exploration](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4860/2012fa/MacKenzie-TheAutomationOfProof.pdf) by Donald Mackenzie, *IEEE Annals of the History of Computing*, Vol. 17, No. 3 (1995), 7-29.